# HMAC generated in Swift unequal to HMAC in NodeJS ONLY SOMETIMES

Tags: node.js, swift, hash, cryptography, hmac

I have discovered a HUGE issue in my code, and I have literally no idea what is causing this.

SO, when I send requests to my server I hash a string thats in the request. This is sometimes user input.

My app is multi language so I have to support all "ä" chars etc.

So with the normal english letters/chars numbers etc, this hashing method works like a dream. BUT when the string being hashed and compared contains a "ä" or a "ö" (Not specifically those, it literally might be that any char not in the Base64 set will cause this) the hash doesn't match!

This is an absolute and complete disaster, and I have not noticed it this far. I have tried basically everything I know to try to fix this, and googling, and I am out of luck so far.

I generate the hash in Swift inputting the string and secretToken into this function and saving the output as a HTTP header:

```
func hmac(string: String, key: String) -> String {

    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), key, key.count, string, string.count, &digest)

    let data = Data(digest)

    return data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()

}
```

How I compare the hash in NodeJS:

```
if (hashInTheRequest === crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretToken).update(stringToHash).digest('hex')) {
    //Good to go
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered converting your data to raw binary and then hash it? That way, whatever characters you have, the binary should be the same.

Comment: [Normalize](https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html)!